# MIPS Program with Integer and Argument Example

Tags: arguments, mips

I'm stuck on an exercise, and am unsure how to proceed. This is the exercise:

Write a MIPS assembly language procedure, Test, that accepts 2 integers as arguments and 
returns 0 if the integers are equal, 1 if the first is less than the second, and 2 if the first is greater 
than the second. 
Write a MIPS assembly language program that reads in 2 integers, calls the procedure Test, then 
outputs one of the following messages: 
The integers are equal 
The first integer is less than the second 
The first integer is greater than the second

What would be an example to carry this out? Mips is very confusing to me, as I'm used to Java. Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the program I am using as a foundation, since I am unsure where to start:

```
.data 
str1: .asciiz "Please Enter Integer 1: "  # a
str2: .asciiz "Please Enter Integer 2: "  # a
str3: .asciiz "The sum is "  # a
newline: .asciiz "\n"  # g

 .text 
main: addi $v0, $zero, 4   
 la $a0, str1          
 syscall                   

 addi $v0, $zero, 5       
 syscall           

 add $s0, $zero, $v0       

 addi $v0, $zero, 4        
 la $a0, str2          
 syscall               

 addi $v0, $zero, 5        
 syscall               

 add $s1, $zero, $v0       

L1: beq $s1, $zero, cont  
    addi $v0, $zero, 1    
    add $a0, $s0, $zero   
    addi $s1, $s1, -1     
    syscall               
    j L1              

 cont: addi $v0, $zero, 4      
 la $a0, newline       
 syscall           

 addi $v0, $zero, 10       
 syscall           

 jr $ra
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Which part is confusing you? Can you take input alright? Can you compare integers alright? Do you understand branching? Give us some code and you'll be 10x more likely to get code back

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where to start, so I am using a previously made program as a foundation, and trying to manipulate it in order to work with my above question. Here is the code:

Comment: Do you need help creating a sub-process?

Comment: I just need to modify the Loop/Calculation part. So instead of it printing the first integer, by the amount in the second integer, I need it to return 0 if the integers are equal, 1 if the first is less than the second, and 2 if the first is greater than the second. And then output the corresponding messages:
"The integers are equal", 
"The first integer is less than the second", or 
 "The first integer is greater than the second".

Answer (score -1):

To check whether one register's value is smaller than another register's value, we can use the
set-on-less-than instruction, which also has a set-on-less-than-immediate counterpart.

slt $r0, $r3, $r4
()if r3 < r4, r0 is set to 1
else r0 is set to 0
slti $r0, $r3, 10
()if r3 < 10, r0 is set to 1
else r0 is set to 0

slt and slti are similar to beq or bne, however, there are two differences. First, they test
whether one value is smaller than another value and, second, they don't branch to some
address, but, instead, set a flag, stored in the first operand.